# MIPS error after assemble

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am starting with MIPS and I have to do a simple program

```
.text  #text section
.globl main  #call main by MARS
main:
addi $t1, $0, 10  #load immediate value (10)
addi $t2, $0, 11 #load immediate value (11)
add $t3, $t1, $t2  #add two numbers into $t3
jr $ra   #return from main; return address
```

It assembles with no errors, but when I press play it gives me this error

Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

Go: execution terminated with errors.

I don't know what exactly this mean anyone can help?

Comment: Means execution somehow reached the address `0`. The program looks fine though.

Answer (score 1):

SPIM places sort of a crt0 ahead of your code. That is, a small piece of code that will do a `JAL` to your `main`, and if you return back to the startup code it will perform a system call 10 to terminate the program.

MARS on the other hand doesn't place any such code before your code. So there you'd be returning back to "nowhere" when you do `jr $ra` from main. You should instead end your program with a system call 10, i.e.

```
# instead of jr $ra, do:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score -1):

```
jr $ra   #return from main; return address
```

Where are you returning to? Your main method wasn't called by another method, therefore when you try to return to an address, there is no return address because you haven't made a jump. Remove that line and it should work.